# Titanium Backup: How to restore user apps and data without system apps and data?

Tags: restore, titanium-backup

Is there a way to restore user and system data separately with Titanium Backup?

I would like to restore only my user apps and data (excluding system apps and data). The only way to achieve this seems to be to select "Restore all apps with data" in the Restore section and manually uncheck all system apps.

This is certainly doable but becomes tedious if you restore your device often. Is there a more convenient option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on `Click to Edit Filters` in the `Backup \ Restore` tab in Titanium Backup you can select:

Filter by type:

> System
>
> User
>
> Uninstalled

Then you can restore all apps that are only filtered by these (or a combination of them).

[image]